# Media Query in SCSS - Syntax Error

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Is there something about @media queries that I'm missing because I keep seeing the following compilation error from my SCSS file:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "​"
        on line 584 of site/assets/scss/_custom-styles.scss
>> }​
```

I have placed my media query between 2 normal CSS styles. Is this ok. Why am i seeing this error:

```
.homeDivParent {
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("/assets/479305270.jpg");
  background-position: 20% 0%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  //background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-width:1400px) {
    .homeDivParent {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}​

.whiteFont {
  //background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'AbMedium';
}
```

Comment: That compiles without errors when I paste it into http://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: I also see nothing wrong.  Are you certain that the above code is what caused you errors?

Comment: There is an unwanted character after the media query styles? [Check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhnfck3m/)

Comment: @Vucko many many thanks - that was it. I deleted the lines, and retyped, all ok! Trivial, annoying!

Answer (score 0):

if saving your `.scss` too fast, you could miss compiling your `sass` code repeatedly, so the `.css` file will be storing the previous compiled styles.

If you find it happening, just make a brief change and `save` again, check if changed.

**ps.** I can't comment due my yet low reputation, but I do hope it would be useful in the future.